# Convergence of $\int\limits_1^{\pi/2}\frac{\pi\cos^3(x)}{x^{2/3}-x^{1/2}}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

> Determine if $\displaystyle\int\limits_1^{\pi/2}\frac{\pi\cos^3(x)}{x^{2/3}-x^{1/2}}\,\mathrm dx$ is convergent.

As a tutor of around 6 years predominantly working with calc I and calc II students, this question completely stumped me.

I felt I was going in the right direction by trying to use some kind of comparison test with $-\pi\int\limits_{\pi/2}^1 \dfrac 1{x^{2/3}-x^{1/2}}\,\mathrm dx$, but I think not having infinity as a bound completely throws me off. I don't think it's as hard as I'm making it, but after an hour, I just couldn't think of anything.

Any help would be extremely appreciated so I can better understand how to deal with these kinds of problems in the future.

Comment: Please try to avoid using `a \over b` while typesetting. It makes editing more tedious than it needs to be, particularly when `a` and `b` are long expressions. `\frac{a}{b}` is the way to go. Also, using `\displaystyle` for complicated expressions in inline math mode certainly helps with readability if you do not wish to use display math mode `$$...$$`

Answer (score 2):

The only pole of the integrand is $1$. As $x\rightarrow 1$,
$$ \begin{aligned} \frac{1}{x^{2/3}-\sqrt{x}} &= \frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{3}(x-1)+o(x-1)-1-\frac{1}{2}(x-1)+o(x-1)} \\
&= \frac{1}{\frac{1}{6}(x-1)+o(x-1)} \\
&= \frac{6}{x-1}(1+o(1))
\end{aligned} $$
Therefore
$$ \frac{\cos^3(x)}{x^{2/3}-\sqrt{x}}\underset{x\rightarrow 1}{\sim}\frac{6\cos^3(1)}{x-1} $$
thus the integral diverges.